# PHP Symfony 2 decodes uri before resolving path handlers

Tags: php, symfony, uri

It seems PHP Symfony decodes the url before matching the paths. So request to `/foo/{bar}` will be same as request to `/foo%2F{bar}`. I hope this is not intentional. Because then I can't actually make a request to `/foo/xyz%2Fabc`. I can't put a urlencoded slash in any dynamic path.

Comment: Are you sure this is not caused by your server setup? If you're sure it's not, then it looks like a severe problem.